# Remove extra escaped double quotes from list of Clojure strings

Tags: string, clojure, hashmap, escaping, double-quotes

I have a file: matches.txt which looks like this:

```
"key1"
"key2"
"key3"
```

When I read it into memory:

```
(with-open [r reader "matches.txt")] (doall (line-seq r)))
```

I get the following list structure that has quoted strings that have escaped double quotes:

```
("\"key1\""
 "\"key2\""
 "\"key3\"")
```

Let's call that result 'key-list'.  I've tried many hash-map look ups, for example:

```
(test-hash-map (first key-list))
```

and none of them work.

I would like to get these entries converted so that I can use them to retrieve a hash-map entry.

Either:

- Remove the escaped double quotes from the in-memory list structure, or
- Read the strings in from the matches.txt file without the double double quotes.

Comment: There are no "escaped double quotes" in the list. There are only the quotes that the text file provided. Your idea No.2, to strip those quotes upon reading the file, is the way to go. You could use the clojure.data.csv library (which has lots of features for reading comma-separated, maybe-quoted fields), or you could use clojure.string/replace as you would in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since quoted strings are the edn format for strings you could use [clojure.edn/read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string) to convert your strings removing the quote delimiters (assuming all of your lines are delimited by quotes):

```
> (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "matches.txt")] 
     (doall (map clojure.edn/read-string (line-seq rdr))))
("key1" "key2" "key3")
```

[clojure.core/read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) could be used as well, but note the warning that

> ... read-string can execute code (controlled by *read-eval*), and as
> such should be used only with trusted sources.